# Added a new PageLayout to my feature but it's not showing in SharePoint?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, page-layout

I had an existing feature that deployed a Page Layout.  I ended up adding another Page Layout to the feature and I updated my Elements.xml file to include the reference to the new file:

```
  <File Url="MNCRFPPage.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true">
    <Property Name="Title" Value="MNC RFP Page" />
    <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
    <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/DefaultPageLayout.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/DefaultPageLayout.png" />
    <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#MNC RFP Site Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007A48130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3987686902DCEDA048E5B29BDA9E09CD73FD006B86C4A7F5F7EE489F15C53271E48D84;#"/>
  </File>
```

If I go to my 14 hive after deploying I see the new file and the updated Elements.xml file, but for some reason when I go to `Site Settings->Galleries->Master pages and page layouts` it's not showing up.

Am I missing a step here?  Can anyone think of a reason that this file would not be showing up in the Page Layouts gallery?

Comment: Should work.. Did you activate feature?

Comment: Did you deploy it for this particular site? Did you check for the file in SP Designer?

Comment: Yes it is activated.  I deployed to a specific site, but have not checked with SP Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you use module for deploying pagelayouts.
have u mentioned the path like below

> `<Module Name="MasterPagesGallery" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">`

and also i believe you have deactivated and activated the feature after deploying

Comment: Yep, looks like I just needed to deactivate and reactivate...

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to include File in Module element as shown below:

```
<Module Name="MasterPages" 
          Url="_catalogs/masterpage" 
          Path="PageLayouts"
          RootWebOnly="TRUE">

    <File Url="Test.aspx" 
              Type="GhostableInLibrary">

      <Property Name="Title" Value="Home page" />
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
      <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#$Resources:SE_OSU_ResourcesContentTypes,ctype_homepage_name;;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390028F91F325164A04A99A6579038281757004EB0B00A3F7C9847B809A3D61B8C7499;#" />
    </File>
 </Module>
```

Comment: Yes, it is in the Module

Answer (score 1):

I also added `ReplaceContent="True"` to each file element to overwrite the previous installed version.

For example:

```
<File Url="Communications/iNewsArticle.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" ReplaceContent="true">
```